# Copy files from s3 bucket to another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, bucket

Is it possible to send/sync files from source AWS S3 bucket into destination S3 bucket on a different AWS account, in a different location?

I found this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

But if I understand it correctly, this is the way how to sync files from destination account.

Is there a way how to do it other way around? Accessing destination bucket from source account (using source IAM user credentials).

Comment: How have you been granted access to write to the destination bucket that belongs to a different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That needs the right IAM and Bucket policy settings.

A detailed configuration for cross account access, is discussed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)

Once you have it configured you can perform sync,

> aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket  s3://destinationbucket --recursive

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

AWS finally came up with a solution for this: [S3 batch operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops.html).

> S3 Batch Operations is an Amazon S3 data management feature that lets
>   you manage **billions of objects** at scale with just a few clicks in the
>   Amazon S3 Management Console or a single API request. With this
>   feature, you can make changes to object metadata and properties, or
>   perform other storage management tasks, such as **copying objects
>   between buckets**, replacing object tag sets, modifying access controls,
>   and restoring archived objects from S3 Glacier — instead of taking
>   months to develop custom applications to perform these tasks.

It allows you to replicate data at bucket, prefix or object level, from any region to any region, between any storage class (e.g. S3 <> Glacier) and **across AWS accounts**! No matter if it's thousands, millions or billions of objects.

This introduction video has an overview of the options (my apologies if I almost sound like a salesperson, I'm just very excited about it as I have a couple of million objects to copy ;-) https://aws.amazon.com/s3/s3batchoperations-videos/

Comment: Warning: Don't make the same mistake as I did as I didn't check all costs accurately. I backupped multimillion files from S3 to Glacier with Batch Operations PUT Copy and only checked storage and data transfer pricing. Afterward, I found out that PUT operations to Glacier are 10x pricier than S3 which resulted in a huge spike in costs (>$1000). But for the rest, it worked like charm.